# javascript swiper library in an angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How would I initialize swiper library inside an angular js directive.

Especially when the directive has the slides created with a ng-repeat

Here is my first attempt on a plukr.
http://plnkr.co/edit/LFV3Y1lxOl8GFmL2M3mP

And here is the library 
http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Comment: Ok, I got it semi working. The only problem now is the data binding breaks in the ng-repeat.

http://plnkr.co/edit/JUkBe6tULkWL2Jx343tx?p=preview

Answer (score 5):

i do it :) please check [angularjs-idangero.us-swiper](https://github.com/arastu/angularjs-idangero.us-swiper) repo
this work in dynamic view in routing and have a tricky solution for mix ng-click and onSlideClick
download repo and extract it, copy angularjs-idangero.us-swiper-master to xampp htdoc(or wamp or any web server) and go to `localhost/angularjs-idangero.us-swiper-master/#/test` to see demo

Answer (score 3):

i recently had the same problem. found this answer on reddit:
http://as.reddit.com/r/angularjs/comments/1ksa5k/help_getting_swiper_to_work_in_a_directive_with/

his solution:
http://plnkr.co/edit/JUkBe6tULkWL2Jx343tx?p=preview

User deathcarrot wrote there:
Looks like swiper is screwing with your DOM when it loads up which breaks the bindings. Run swiper({...}) in your swiperDirective link function before you've added any content and then run mySwiper.reInit() in doReady once you're ready to activate it. Might also need to $watchCollection your ng-repeat data and reInit() whenever that changes so it updates the slides.

this is how I use it in my project:

in the html-file i added two custom directives (`swiper-directive` and `swiper-slide` to the whole swiper-div-thing

```
   <div class="swiper-container" swiper-directive>
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide" ng-repeat="item in data" swiper-slide>
            {{$index}} : {{item}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

in my angular.run function i added a function `updateSwiper()` to the rootscope:

```
var mySwiper;
var myApp= angular.module('testApp',[])
    .run( function($log, $rootScope, $http, $templateCache){
          $rootScope.updateSwiper = function () {
              mySwiper.reInit();
          }
    }
```

the directives I defined like this:

```
myApp.directive("swiperDirective", ["$rootScope", function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        controller: function() {
            this.ready = function() {
                $rootScope.updateSwiper();
            }
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            mySwiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
                loop:false
            });
        }
    }
}]);

myApp.directive("swiperSlide", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "^swiperDirective",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            if(scope.$last) {
                ctrl.ready();
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

so basically the `link: function` in the swiperSlide-directive gets called for every created slide. Every element in ng-repeat has its own scope, and only the last item in our data-array has $last defined, so it obviously hits the function `ctrl.ready()`. This then calls the function `$rootScope.updateSwiper` where finally our swiper gets reinitalized.

With this, swiper works really well with angular, also on mobile (phonegap). So I hope this is what you were looking for...

Answer (score 1):

I have never managed to make tschueggi solution to work but I came up with this one :

```
    .directive('waitForSlider1', function ($timeout){
    return {
        link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            if ($scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    new Swiper('.swiper-container1',{
                      //Your options here:
                      mode:'horizontal',
                      loop: true,
                      slidesPerView: 1,
                      pagination: '.pagination1'
                    });
                });
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The only problem I have now is that ng-click won't work anymore. Any Idea why ?

Fred

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Keep in mind that [Stack Overflow is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92107). If you have a problem with a possible answer, it might be better to first post [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) to find a solution to the problem before posting it as an answer. Either way, you may want to remove all the text after the code in your answer.